# Overriding VertexColors to shade a particular face

Tags: three.js

I have a PLY model that comes with all of its color information in the file, so I'm using `{vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors}` when I define its `MeshBasicMaterial` to pull these colors in. This all renders nicely.

I'd like to be able to raycast to the surface and update a face's color when the mouse is over it. I have no problems getting the face information from the ray intersects, and when I try updating the face's color using a model that's *not* defined by its `vertexColors`, everything works as it should. When I try it with any model that *is* defined this way, though, it never updates the selected face.

Any ideas on what's causing this or how to resolve it? Is there a way to override the color information that's set by `THREE.VertexColors` in order to highlight a face?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try setting `geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;`? Just a wild guess, but maybe helps. (see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates)

Comment: Yep, I'm calling that immediately after updating the face's color. I also have `geometry.dynamic = true` during the geometry object's initial declaration.